# Django/JS - Can't set default value for an already liked post

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, django-views

I want to check conditional on each post if the logged in user has liked it or not, accordingly I want to pass in a context which assigns the button a CSS class for the **default value of color when the page loads**.

I don't want to use to use HTML if/else condition as I'm using JavaScript to change the color of the button when clicked.

Even though I'm able to change the color once I click but I'm stuck at how to pass in the default condition of the post whenever the page loads.

This is the JavaScript code :

```
window.onload = function(){
  var thumb_up = document.getElementById('thumb_up');
  thumb_up.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  thumb_up.onclick = function(){
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var id = this.getAttribute('data-id');
    var url = '/api/like/'+id+'?format=json';
    req.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if(this.readyState==4 && this.status==200){
        // var data = eval(req.responseText);
        data = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
        var likes = data.likes;
        document.getElementById('likes-count').innerHTML = likes+' votes';
        //changing color
        if(data.liked=='true'){
          thumb_up.className = "material-icons thumb_up_liked";
        } else{
          thumb_up.className = "material-icons thumb_up";
        }
      }
    };
    req.open("GET", url, true);
    req.send();
  }
}
```

Also, I tried sending the default value for CSS/HTML class from backend, but I'm messing up the syntax. Can't figure out the logic to send it from backend either.

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    #generic format : <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    template_name = 'home_login.html'
    context_object_name = 'post'
    ordering = ['-date']
    paginate_by = 5

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        post = Post.objects.all()
        post_self = self.get_object()
        class_name = "thumb_up_liked"
        context = {
            'class': class_name,
            'post': post,
        }
        if request.user in post_self.likes.all():
            return render(request, 'home_login.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can collect the value of context variable `class` in a javascript variable in your `home_login.html` file as:

```
<script>
   var thumbs_class = {{ class }};
</script>
```

Then you can use this value in your javascript code at required place as:

```
thumb_up.className = "material-icons "+ thumbs_class;
```

Make sure that your above javascript loads after declaration of the variable.

Comment: I'm able to toggle it using JS, the main issue is when the page loads it goes back to default value if I set one.
Also, I'm unable to send the context variable, looks like the syntax is all wrong in that django function.